# How to implement Twilio android push notifications in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification

I'm trying to implement Twilio push notification in my react-native app for android but I have got some errors. Please help me, how I can integrate notifications to android.

Comment: Can you share what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Agreed with @RansakaRavihara - please share some code and the errors you are seeing and any other steps needed to recreate the issue. Ideally, a jsfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: I dont get errors as such , but when i send any pushnotification i do not get it
I followed the steps at "https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/android" and "https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/configure-android-push-notifications"
but then it was crashing . I soon reliased that the classes mentioned in manifest are missing
I then checked the github sample app at "https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/notifications-quickstart-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/notify/quickstart" and 
i added proper classes but then i got these errors

Comment: can you please suggest proper steps?
i am clear on steps on twilio side but am i missing something on android native app side?

Comment: yes @gauravsbagul I got these same errors.

Answer (score 0):

@monikaj is this error you are getting

[image]